# What the word Leads mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

At follow context:

> Selling Leads and Buying Leads

what leads means ?

Comment: This is a case where I don't think there's more than one commonly used meaning.  But note your [meaning-in-context] tag and question "At follow context" ("in the following context" would be more idiomatic).  Context is the surrounding, related text that explains the setting in which the terms are used, and that's usually critical to the meaning.  Often words have multiple meanings or nuances, so asking here for simple dictionary definitions may not be adequate to fully understand how they're used.  In general, it's important to include the actual context when you ask about word meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It is an expression from **marketing**, which [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_generation) explains as follows:

> In marketing, lead generation is the initiation of **consumer interest or enquiry into products or services of a business**. Leads can be created for purposes such as list building, e-newsletter list acquisition or for sales leads. The methods for generating leads typically fall under the umbrella of advertising, but may also include non-paid sources such as organic search engine results or referrals from existing customers.

More information on different leads can be found behind the link.

Comment: Just to more directly address the question, a "lead" is contact information for a person who might be a potential customer (a sales lead).  Companies often buy and sell their customer lists for this purpose.  There are also companies that just research and compile lists of potential customers for different kinds of products and services and sell those lists to companies looking to expand their customer base.  Buying and selling leads refers to the purchase and sale of that kind of contact information for potential customers.

Answer (score -2):

> **What is a Lead? - Sales Glossary**
>
> - A lead, in a marketing context, is a potential sales contact: an individual or organization that expresses an interest in your goods or
>     services. Leads are typically obtained through the referral of an
>     existing customer, or through a direct response to
>     advertising/publicity.
> - A sales lead is a prospective consumer of a product or service, created when an individual or  business shows interest and provides contact information. Businesses
>     gain access to sales leads through advertising, trade shows, direct
>     mailings and other marketing efforts. They can also purchase sales
>     leads from third-party companies. A sales lead is not a sales
>     prospect; further qualification of the lead is necessary to determine
>     intent and interest.
> - The precise definition of a 'lead' tends to vary somewhat from person
>     to person. In fact, one of the biggest stumbling blocks between sales
>     and marketing can be the definition of what counts as a lead and what
>     doesn't. It's important to make sure that everyone involved in lead
>     generation is in agreement with the people responsible for following
>     up on those leads.
> - Most salespeople define a lead as someone who matches the criterion
>     the salesperson has established and who has the need, reason and/or
>     interest in pursuing the product.
> - However, marketing professionals tend to define a lead as anyone who
>     might have those qualities, and believe that a lead that proves to
>     have the desired attributes is considered to be a 'prospect.'
>
> Both of these definitions are reasonable. The important thing is to
>   make sure that everyone involved agrees as to which definition they'll
>   be using. If you're reading advice on a sales site (such as this one),
>   for instance, you can assume that the writer is using the first,
>   sales-related definition of a lead, while marketing writers will more
>   often use the second definition.   Some sales experts prefer to use
>   the term 'suspect' instead of lead, partly to eliminate the confusion
>   that can arise from multiple definitions. Referring to someone as a
>   suspect versus a prospect is also a very clear way to categorize how
>   far along the sales process you are with a given lead. Someone you've
>   just seen on a lead list and haven't called yet is a suspect; someone
>   you've at least partially qualified is a prospect.
>
> Not all leads are equally valuable from a sales perspective. First,
>   some lead sources will provide a high percentage of 'junk' leads,
>   meaning leads that don't have the potential to be prospects. For
>   example, if you use the phone book as your lead source, then the
>   majority of the people you call will be junk leads.
>
> That's one reason why salespeople (and companies) are willing to pay
>   quite a lot of money to buy high-quality lead lists. The more targeted
>   and accurate a lead list is, the less time the salesperson will have
>   to waste on non-prospects.
>   [The Balance](https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-a-lead-2917360)